# Python - Tkinter call a class with arguments

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two classes.

```
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Application")
        self.geometry(f'1000x600+200+50')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.create_widgets()
        
        SubmitButton(self.window_frame_1, 10, 130)

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.window_frame_1 = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text = 'ADDING PEOPLE')
        self.window_frame_1.place(x = 50, y = 30, width = 900, height = 250)

        self.window_frame_2 = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text = 'LIST OF PEOPLES')
        self.window_frame_2.place(x = 50, y = 300, width = 900, height = 250)

class SubmitButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, margin_x, margin_y):   
        super().__init__(parent, margin_x, margin_y,
                         text = 'Adaugare',
                         cursor = 'hand2',
                         border = 0,
                         background = '#0463cc',
                         activebackground = '#0079FF',
                         foreground = '#ffffff',
                         activeforeground = '#ffffff', 
                         font = ('Helvetica', 8, 'bold'))
        self.place(x = margin_x, y = margin_y, width = 150, height = 35)
```

When I call SubmitButton class with my arguments, SubmitButton(self.window_frame_1, 10, 130) I get the error:

```
super().__init__(parent, margin_x, margin_y,
TypeError: Button.__init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

In the same way, I created a class for input fields, but when I call it, it works; only to the SubmitButton class no.

I searched on Google for a solution but I did not reach a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `error` you are facing  is because you're passing `additional` arguments `(margin_x and margin_y)` to the Button class's `__init__` method, which only expects one positional argument `(self)`.
- remove `margin_x` and `margin_y` arguments from the `super().__init__()` call in the SubmitButton class.

```
class SubmitButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, margin_x, margin_y):   
        super().__init__(parent,
                         text='Adaugare',
                         cursor='hand2',
                         border=0,
                         background='#0463cc',
                         activebackground='#0079FF',
                         foreground='#ffffff',
                         activeforeground='#ffffff', 
                         font=('Helvetica', 8, 'bold'))
        self.place(x=margin_x, y=margin_y, width=150, height=35)
```

Comment: Oh. It's my carelessness. In the other classes, I did not put arguments in super() either.
Thank you very much for your help.